# Why Can't I push to gitlab repository?

Tags: authentication, gitlab, push, ssh-keys

I recently created a new gitlab repository, and have set up a repository deployment key with the ssh public key from my computer. I manage to clone the project with ssh, but when I try to push changes into the repository, I get returned with a fatal error:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to push all the following should be implemented first

1. Make sure the project has been created under your username on
   GitLab.com.
2. your Git username and email  match your GitLab.com account for this
   repository
3. the remote origin was set:

   git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:user_name/work.git
4. an SSH public key was added to your GitLab.com account (if cloning
   over using git or ssh).

   ssh -T git@gitlab.com

Otherwise you could create a specific access token for the project you want to write to

The following guide could be useful https://blog.programster.org/gitlab-create-a-projects-access-token

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is alittle more complicated than that. I cloned the project on a virtual machine shared with another team member which will also have access to this git repository. That's why I decided to use a deployment key for one specified repository, instead of a ssh key shared to my account. I wanted the VM to have access to only this git repository and not my other projects on gitlab. Its a security concern if I use a ssh key to my gitlab.com account.

Comment: What about a specific token, for the project you want to have access to. Updated the answer with a link to a guide